# Permanent network drive mount in fstab not working (due to network not being online whilst attempting to mount)

Tags: centos, mount, fstab

I have a network drive hosted on a Windows10 Machine, it mounts fine to my CentOS7 machine through the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mountpoint --verbose -o credentials:/credential/file/location,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777
```

The file and dir modes are for the permissions on the mount. Anyway, that mounts fine, but when I try to do an /etc/fstab mount, I get an error back.

I will supply my entire fstab file contents and the exact error below. The error appears on startup, it boots to emergency mode and shows the error and gives me the option to use CTRL + D to continue.

The `fstab` mount I am trying to get to work is:

```
//ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt cifs credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,uid=1001,gid=1001,_netdev 0 0
```

My `/etc/fstab` contents:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Dec 13 09:33:55 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=4f3871fe-a798-4d51-ad90-c40b095a2bd0 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=1bb03b6d-3a76-4979-aa63-ff3e0eb4cc5f /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=f89fdb96-6dbf-4865-aa6b-1d5cc74f2d48 /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=86f38c73-f9e0-490b-8c96-3321f9413c0d swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
//ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt cifs credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,uid=1001,gid=1001,_netdev 0 0
```

The error appears on startup and you can find it below:
**You're looking at the CIFS bit, the bad mount option huge needs sorting anyway, that was there before the fstab cifs mount. Thanks**

[image: error]

---

**@telcoM's answer response**

I rebooted and get the following error on startup:
[image: error after trying @telcoM's answer]

Then when I login after seeing the error, I get a shortcut appear in the left of my file browser, when I click it, I get this error:

`Unable to mount 'shared-folder-name', mount: only root can mount //ipaddress/sharedfoldername on /mountpoint`

---

**MY `FSTAB` FILE AFTER @TELCOM'S SUGGESTION**

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Dec 11 14:28:31 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=4d48ab0d-e1ab-4d7e-9f64-8481a7690060 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=a7fad550-81d7-4150-8b76-e89584e4cfdf /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=0baabbc4-2dc0-4971-9d2b-c123e5ad7355 /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=7756eafb-382c-46b3-aae8-e44d7e2cfe06 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
#
//ipadress/sharedfoldername /mount/location cifs x-systemd.after=network-online.target,credentials=/credentials/location,vers=3.0,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

Comment: Subquestion added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tmpfs: Bad mount option huge` turns out to be a kernel bug: see [this link.](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16414)

The "Error connecting to a socket" means the system is trying to mount the Windows share before network interfaces have been fully enabled. It should not be happening, but you could add a new systemd-style mount option to be explicit about it: `x-systemd.after=network-online.target`. The `_netdev` option used to be an old way to do the same, but apparently it does not work any more after CentOS moved to `systemd` in version 7.0.

[As i wrote in my answer to your earlier question,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591280/258991) if you want everyone to be able to access the share, you'll need to supply the mount options `file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777`. And if you do this, then the `uid=1001,gid=1001` options will probably be unnecessary, but you can still use them if you want.

And to silence an ugly warning about a changed default version of the SMB protocol (since the aftermath of the WannaCry ransomware infestation back in May 2017), you'll want to add `vers=3.0` mount option too, if the share is provided by a reasonably modern version of Windows.

So, the `/etc/fstab` entry should probably be like this (split to multiple lines for readability):

```
//ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mnt cifs 
x-systemd.after=network-online.target,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,
vers=3.0,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

An `fstab` entry should always have exactly 6 fields separated by whitespace - no more and no less.

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks! - What do you mean by: "An `fstab` entry should always have exactly 6 fields separated by whitespace - no more and no less."

Comment: Please see my response to your question in my answer at the bottom - It hasn't worked and I get an error back.

Comment: I tend to use .automount systemd units instead of fstab entries for network mounts, just because it's so hard to be sure that the network is *really* up when the network-online target arrives.

Comment: @jsbillings Before you posted that - I had a go at using this: `x-systemd.after=network-online.target,noauto,x-systemd.automount` and it's worked!

Comment: @jsbillings However, I've got a duplicate shortcut down the left side of my file browser now, both just saying Shared and linking to the same place, how can I remove one?

Comment: @telcoM However, I've got a duplicate shortcut down the left side of my file browser now, both just saying Shared and linking to the same place, how can I remove one?

Comment: It's the same gtk bookmarks file you edited earlier.

Comment: @jsbillings No - that's empty, its not where the shortcuts are held, it's just above that. It's only happening for one of my drives. It duplicates the desktop shortcut too

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're talking about?  Or create a new question?

Comment: @jsbillings Sorted - thanks, however do you know about this? [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592027/samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7-or-raspberry-pi)

Comment: @jsbillings Another problem - I think you would know this one: [INTERNAL LINK: unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)

Comment: telcoM Another problem - do you know how this would work? [INTERNAL LINK: unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)

Answer (score 1):

The working line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//ipadress/sharedfoldername /mountpoint cifs x-systemd.after=network-online.target,noauto,x-systemd.automount,credentials=/credentials/location,vers=3.0,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

@telcoM has helped loads with getting to this result.

Comment: Rather than posting your own repeat of another answer, please accept the answer that has best helped you. You could add a comment to the answer to say that you had to add `x-systemd.automount` to the options, if you felt that would be helpful.